# C++ Compiler Deducing Incorrect Template Parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to figure out why the following fails to compile when I pass in the variable "a" as an lvalue to attach(), but compiles fine when I pass it in an rvalue, e.g. with std::move().

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {}
    ~Test() {}

    bool func(char c)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename T1, typename... T2>
bool attach(C& obj,
            R(C::*func)(T1,T2...), T1&& arg1, T2&&... args)
{
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test test;
    char a = 'a';
    attach<bool,Test,char>(test, &Test::func, a);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here, why isn't "a" deduced as an lvalue according to the template collapsing rules?

Comment: There is no deduction happening here - you've explicitly specified all template parameters. `T1&&` is `char&&` since you explicitly set `T1` to be `char`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you find a duplicate of this? I was unable to find one with my quick search

Comment: BTW, there are 2 places to deduce `T1`, and that would mismatch in your case.

Comment: Ok, so if I call attach() without explicitly giving it template parameters, it still fails to compile, but I see it's because func() now has the wrong signature (should require an lvalue reference) - I think @Jarod42 was alluding to this. Thanks!

Comment: That would fix the error, but it makes your `attach` function less useful. Typically you would write the function as `template <typename R, typename C, typename... T1, typename... T2> bool attach(C& obj, R(C::*func)(T1...), T2&&... args)` so the member function's parameter types and the argument types you pass to `attach` are independently deduced. You can perform SFINAE or `static_assert` using `is_convertible` to do error checking if you wish.

Comment: @Praetorian: or simply: `template <typename C, typename Invokable, typename ... T1> bool attach(C& obj,  Invokable&& func, T1&&... args)`.